# How to add time interval by 1 min to NSDate object in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I am able to get any location local time.My requirement is,once i fetch local time, i need to add 1 min after each min to NSDate.for ex: i am getting time like this:11:22 and i m able to display in next min it should be 11:23.

Please help me.

Comment: I think this is what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440837/how-to-add-time-in-current-time

Comment: Please chech this answer 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019709/add-90-min-to-nsdate/29542106#29542106

Answer (score 10):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *datePlusOneMinute = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
```

Answer (score 2):

Omarj's answer looks good for simple testing purposes, but I like to use this code:

```
NSDateComponents *changeComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
changeComponent.second = 20;

NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *newDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:changeComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

As you can probably see, you can change changeComponent to minutes, hours, days, or in my case, seconds! This is very useful for testing local notifications which I am currently working on.

The best benefit of this solution is that it takes into account the calendar, so there should be no problems adding on hours when Daylight Saving Time changes for example.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this code.

```
    NSString* dateString = @"9:33AM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Before Adding time %@",date);
NSDate *newDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:14*60];
NSLog(@"After adding time %@",[formatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```